# I'm new to bayes' theorem, is my step for the question below correctly? Can someone also help me out with the last question?

Tags: statistics, bayesian, bayes-theorem

the number of claims, n, and the total claim size y from the previous year,
during which there were n = 10 claims with a total claim amount of y = 7.3

n = number of claims

y = total claim size

The number of claims in any given year follows a Poisson(λ) distribution with λ = 12

The individual claim sizes follow a Gamma(2, θ) distribution where θ is unknown.

Given θ, claim sizes are independent of each other.

1. Identify a suitable prior π(θ) and briefly justify your choice
2. Derive the posterior density π(θ|n, y).
3. Now let n’ and z denote the number of claims and total claim amount respectively. Given n’ , derive the posterior predictive density π(z| n’, y). Hence find an expression for π(z|n, y) as an infinite sum.

[My working is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4yji.jpg)